# Only update/refresh child component

Tags: reactjs, redux

I created a table with data fetched from a server. I'm using the code below to update the data every xx seconds but when it updates it refreshes the page. As a user this gets really annoying because whatever you were doing gets reset.

So I'm trying to find a way to only make my table update without the rest of the component refreshing.

Container > table > rows is my component hierarchy.

```
setTimeout(() => store.dispatch(fetchData('shops')), i);
```

fetchData()

```
        return Object.assign({}, state, {
            items: action.dataSet,
            lastUpdated: action.receivedAt
        });
```

Thanks!

I am using react and redux.

Edit:
I feel like I didn't explain my problem very well so I updated the question. Maybe its better now?

Comment: If your `items` is object you should use deep comparison - https://lodash.com/docs#isEqual

Comment: I don't understand what you mean: update the data but not render the data?

Comment: sorry, I misunderstood.

Comment: Wait can you explain this more? You want to dispatch the action and not re-render?

Comment: Table renders name and value. On update I just want the value to change without a re-render.

Comment: You will update data, but there will no visual changes? If i'm right, when will you re-render your rows?

Comment: Shouldn't your `shouldComponentUpdate` function return true at some point in order for it to re-render. Else, as far as i can see, it's just returning false or undefined, meaning it'll never re-render

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way would be to keep *two* arrays in your reducer. One for "loaded" items, and one for "incoming" items.

```
const initialState = {
  loaded: [],
  incoming: []
};
```

Then your component could depend only on the `loaded` array. When new items are fetched, you'd append them to the `incoming` array:

```
function incoming(state, action) {
  return {
    ...state,
    incoming: state.incoming.concat(action.incoming)
  };
}
```

Maybe later on you want to click a button that dumps your `incoming` items onto the `loaded` array so that your table now displays your queued items:

```
function loadQueuedItems(state) {
  return {
    incoming: [],
    loaded: state.loaded.concat(state.incoming)
  }
}
```

You could then call that function from a reducer when you receive a `LOAD_INCOMING_ITEMS` action or something similar.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

`this.props.data.items !== nextProps.data.items` will return `true` if `items` is an array (which it seems like it is) because when comparing objects in JS (and an array is an object), it is doing a pointer comparison (eg. `this.props.data.items === this.props.data.items` will return `true`).

You either need to do a deep comparison (maybe using something like [lodash's isEqual](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.4#isEqual)) or converting that array to a string like so: `JSON.stringify(this.props.data.items) !== JSON.stringify(nextProps.data.items)`

And some further reading while we're at it! https://ericlathrop.com/2017/02/why-did-this-react-component-rerender/